# Nested Repeaters - have 3 repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I understand the OnItemDatabound attribute on the Parent Repeater ... makes sense

Here is my question:

lets say my data is structured as follows:

```
<List>
Parent Level Movie String
   Next Level : Amenities <List>
       Next level:   Showtimes <List>
```

So I was creating a List of Movies, within that list of Movies is a List of Amenities, within that list of Amenities is the Showtimes

> ```
>  Movies is Repeater 1
>  Amenities is Repeater 2 Child of Repeater 1
>  Showtimes is Repeater 3 Child of Repeater 2
> ```

So, my question is Movies is in a list, and each of the different Repeater items are in a list, can those lists just be used as the DataSource for each Child Repeater, since the data is already contained.

Comment: What you have tried till?

Comment: can you show your list structure?

Comment: I haven't used Nested Repeaters in a while, and all of the examples looked more complicated, so I was trying to substantiate my theory that I could load each repeater with the <list>, but having a main list and embedded lists. this is going to be very simple. Thank you all so much, I will mark the question checked once I get this going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can.  It's not even hard.  Your markup can just look something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />

        <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="Amenities ">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SomeField") %>' />

                <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="Showtimes">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("SomeOtherField") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```